# use Lilypond to transpose pattern around circle of fifths

Tags: lilypond, transposition

I want to provide a pattern (e.g., the C major arpeggio, C E G) and have Lilypond automatically show it transposed (as one score) in all 12 scales.

Here's my current attempt:

```
music = { c' e' g' s }

\new Staff {
  \transpose c c   { \music }
  \transpose c f   { \music }
  \transpose c bes { \music }
  \transpose c ees { \music }
  \transpose c aes { \music }
  \transpose c des { \music }
  \transpose c fis { \music }
  \transpose c b   { \music }
  \transpose c e   { \music }
  \transpose c a   { \music }
  \transpose c d   { \music }
  \transpose c g   { \music }
}
```

I don't know how to add a text above each pattern indicating the transposition key (e.g., C, F, Bb, etc...).  I would like the final product to look something like this:

[image]

Note: I would like this code to work regardless of the length of the pattern (which could be longer than one measure).

Answer (score 4):

Look into the [chord names engraver](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/displaying-chords), which does exactly this and works together perfectly with `\transpose`.

Comment: An answer is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303618/use-lilypond-to-transpose-pattern-around-circle-of-fifths

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
\version "2.18.0"

musicnotes = { c' e' g' s }
music = <<
  \context ChordNames \with { alignAboveContext = "mus" }
  { c1*0 $(skip-of-length musicnotes) }
  \context Staff = "mus" \musicnotes
>>

\new Staff = "mus" {
  \transpose c c   { \music }
  \transpose c f   { \music }
  \transpose c bes { \music }
  \transpose c ees { \music }
  \transpose c aes { \music }
  \transpose c des { \music }
  \transpose c fis { \music }
  \transpose c b   { \music }
  \transpose c e   { \music }
  \transpose c a   { \music }
  \transpose c d   { \music }
  \transpose c g   { \music }
}
```

seems to work.  Note that `\context` does not recreate a context that already exists.

Comment: Adding the documentation: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/special-rhythmic-concerns#aligning-to-cadenzas --- all this time using Lilypond, and I still miss things! Cool function that I'll have to incorporate more where appropriate.

Comment: +1 as it addresses the OP's issue "I would like this code to work regardless of the length of the pattern".

Answer (score 0):

```
\version "2.18.2"

music = { c' e' g' s }
chord = { c1 }

\score {
  <<
    \chords {
      \transpose c c   { \chord }
      \transpose c f   { \chord }
      \transpose c bes { \chord }
      \transpose c ees { \chord }
      \transpose c aes { \chord }
      \transpose c des { \chord }
      \transpose c fis { \chord }
      \transpose c b   { \chord }
      \transpose c e   { \chord }
      \transpose c a   { \chord }
      \transpose c d   { \chord }
      \transpose c g   { \chord }
    }
    \new Staff {
      \transpose c c   { \music }
      \transpose c f   { \music }
      \transpose c bes { \music }
      \transpose c ees { \music }
      \transpose c aes { \music }
      \transpose c des { \music }
      \transpose c fis { \music }
      \transpose c b   { \music }
      \transpose c e   { \music }
      \transpose c a   { \music }
      \transpose c d   { \music }
      \transpose c g   { \music }
    }
  >>
}
```

[image]